# Warning: Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting code paths or name the variable

Tags: warnings

I have a hash table:

```
mapping(address => address[]) private airlineVotes;
```

I am looking to return the table using the function:

```
function addAirlineVotes(address newAirline, address senderAddress) external requireIsOperational returns (address[] memory) {
     airlineVotes[newAirline].push(senderAddress);
}
```

Although the contract compiles, I am being pestered with the warning:

```
> Compilation warnings encountered:

    Warning: Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting code paths or name the variable.
   --> project:/contracts/BoeingData.sol:106:112:
    |
106 |     function addAirlineVotes(address newAirline, address senderAddress) external requireIsOperational returns (address[] memory) {
    |
```

Am I structuring the return value incorrectly or breaking best practices?

Comment: Did you resolve the warning?

Answer (score 4):

The function is declared as returning a `address[] memory`, but the code doesn't return anything.

If you want to return `airlineVotes[newAirline]` use the `return`.

```
function addAirlineVotes(address newAirline, address senderAddress) external requireIsOperational returns (address[] memory) {
    airlineVotes[newAirline].push(senderAddress);
    return airlineVotes[newAirline];
}
```