# Warning when returning no bytes data with checkUpkeep in Chainlink Keeper

Tags: solidity, contract-development, chainlink

From:
`@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol";`

When using:
`checkUpkeep(..) .. override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */)`

I'm not returning `bytes memory /* performData */` but am assigning `upkeepNeeded = true|false` and I get the following warning:

> Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting code paths or name the variable.solidity(6321)

And if I uncomment `bytes memory /* performData */`, then I get

> Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.solidity(5667)

What's the best way to fix this warning?

Answer (score 1):

By "this warning" I've assumed you mean the first one about unnamed return values.

It's just a warning and not a compile-blocking error.  You can ignore it.

Or you can uncomment `/* performData /*` and set performData to be an empty string (empty bytes sequence) like this:

```
function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */) external view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory  performData  ) {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval;
        performData = "";
    }
```

But totally ok to just ignore the warning.

You can also ignore the second warning you referred to, if you uncomment `performData`.  They're both just warnings that are there to bring your attention to situations where you name your return values, but you may not return them or where one is unnamed but in the signature, and may remain unassigned.

See also

- [Warning: Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting code paths or name the variable](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/104120/warning-unnamed-return-variable-can-remain-unassigned-add-an-explicit-return-w)